# Отладка кода API 23

Tags: android-studio

Пытаюсь найти ошибку в программе на api 23. Но в окне логов дальше 3 строки не отображается. На более старших эмуляторах API всё нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как заставить показывать в этом окне лог?

Comment: Внизу выберите вкладку Debug -> Console

Comment: Рядом с Run? Там тоже пусто

Comment: В Debug наверху ещё две вкладки. Нужна Console